# How to get vertical position of scrollbar on Shiny apps?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to get the vertical position of the scrollbar along the whole Shiny app length, i.e, the distance form the top to the position currently scrolled by the user.

I know the following can be done to get the window width in Shiny, and I believe the solution should be something similar:

```
tags$head(tags$script('
                                var dimension = [0, 0];
                                $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                                    dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                                    dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                                    Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
                                });
                                $(window).resize(function(e) {
                                    dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                                    dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                                    Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
                                });
                            ')),
```

Comment: `window.scrollTop`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I believe that points me into the right direction, but I can't get it to work, I know close to nothing about JavaScript

Comment: Hmm... maybe `document.querySelector("body").scrollTop`?

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, after fiddling a while I just found out a solution using `window.pageYOffset` and `$('body').position()`. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to get the vertical scroll position of a Shiny web app using JavaScript and the R package `{shinyjs}`. Below is a minimal reproducible example, in which I create the reactive object `vertical_d()` which represents the numeric value (in pixels) of the scrolling position of the browser, i.e., how far down the user has scrolled on your Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # get vertical scroll position using javascript
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "$(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('scroll', function() {
      Shiny.onInputChange('y_offset', $('body').position());
          });
        });")
  ),
  
  div(h2("Example app")
  ),
  div(
    textOutput("filler_text")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # fill the page with a lot of text
  output$filler_text <- renderText({
    lorem_ipsum <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Neque convallis a cras semper
auctor neque vitae tempus. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Gravida neque
convallis a cras. Semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis. Amet consectetur
adipiscing elit pellentesque. In nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a
scelerisque. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus
magna. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam."
    
    paste(rep(lorem_ipsum, 60), 
          collapse = "\n")
  })
  
  # write scroll position into shiny input
  observeEvent(input$y_offset, {
    runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('y_offset', window.pageYOffset);")
  })
  
  # get input and check if its valid before using it
  vertical <- reactive({
    req(length(input$y_offset) > 0,
        is.numeric(input$y_offset)
    )
    input$y_offset[1]
  })
  
  # debounce input, so that you dont get it updated dozens of time per second. 
  # instead, settle in the value it gets 500 milliseconds after the scrolling stops
  vertical_d <- vertical |> debounce(500)
  
  # print a message in console with vertical screen position
  observe({
    message("vertical scroll position debounced: ", vertical_d())
  })
  
  # display notifications in the browser after some milestones are reached
  observeEvent(vertical_d(), {
    if (vertical_d() < 100) showNotification("You are back at the top of the screen", type = "message")
    
    if (vertical_d() > 100 & vertical_d() < 1000) showNotification("You just scrolled a bit")
    
    if (vertical_d() > 1000 & vertical_d() < 3000) showNotification("You are far down", type = "error")
    
    if (vertical_d() > 3000) showNotification("You have scrolled a lot", type = "error")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can use this code to load reactives or outputs only if the user has scrolled down enough. In my case, I have an app that I know for a fact its very tall (lots of text and figures before some heavy plots and tables), so I wanted to render plots and tables in the lower part of the app only if the user has actually scrolled down, instead of loading everything at the same time when the user opens the web app.